# Laravel Eloquent validation insert exception?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel, eloquent

I've created a form which adds a category of product in a Categories table (for example Sugar Products or Beer), and each user has their own category names.

The Categories table has the columns `id`, `category_name`, `userId`, `created_At`, `updated_At`.

I've made the validation and every thing is okay. But now I want every user to have a unique category_name. I've created this in phpMyAdmin and made a unique index on (`category_name` and `userId`).

So my question is this: when completing the form and let us say that you forgot and enter a category twice... this category exist in the database, and eloquent throws me an error. I want just like in the validation when there is error to redirect me to in my case /dash/warehouse and says dude you are trying to enter one category twice ... please consider it again ... or whatever. I am new in laravel and php, sorry for my language but is important to me to know why is this happens and how i solve this. Look at my controller if you need something more i will give it to you.

```
class ErpController extends Controller{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('pages.erp.dash');
}

public function getWarehouse()
{
    $welcome = Auth::user()->fName . ' ' . Auth::user()->lName;
    $groups = Group::where('userId',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('pages.erp.warehouse', compact('welcome','groups'));


}

public function postWarehouse(Request $request)
{
    $input = \Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'masterCategory' => 'required|min:3|max:80'
    );
    $v = \Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ($v->passes()) {
        $group = new Group;
        $group->group = $input['masterCategory'];
        $group->userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $group->save();
        return redirect('dash/warehouse');
    } else {
        return redirect('dash/warehouse')->withInput()->withErrors($v);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking a question here, always provide sample code pertaining to the question and include a list of solutions you've already tried

Comment: I've edited the grammar of most of your post to make it more clear, but I don't understand your last sentence -- "So now my questions is how when you enter in my form category that exist in Categories Table ".   Can you explain what you are trying to do? Show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a rule like this:

```
$rules = array(
    'category_name' => 'unique:categories,category_name'
);
```